# Javascript error in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a page which is showing a javascript error in IE, stating which line the error is on, but the there are so many linked files I have no idea which line of code it is referring to.

Is there a way to find out which line / linked file it is relating to?? I'm sure I could fix the problem if I knew where it was.

Here is the error message from IE...

```
Message: 'null' is null or not an object
Line: 2231
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: http://www.hpbtenancies.co.uk/location/JF/default.aspx
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be line 2231 in file `default.aspx`? (or is this too obvious :D)

Comment: IE 8 and up have good enough debugging tools, use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens on the line the error reports.. 2231 on default.aspx

```
dd.onchange = function(){ link.href = hrefOrig + dd.value;
```

The detailed error is

> dd is null

---

Use Firefox which has better reporting and also use FireBug for even more flexibility in debugging javascript..

IE 8+ also has improved javascript debugging tools. In the console you will see

> **SCRIPT5007:** Unable to set value of the property '***onchange***': object is null or undefined 
>   default.aspx, line 2231 character 5

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the page with the error, click 'View source', scroll down until you reach line 2231 - that's where your error is.